# Rails refresh a page web view from a dynamic from the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a dynamic view in my database. I am using Postgres and this is my view

```
CREATE VIEW CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS AS
SELECT 
    concat_ws(' ', consultants.first_name, consultants.last_name) as consultant_name,
    clients.name as client_name,
    tasks.name as task_name,
    tasks.init_time::date as task_date,
    EXTRACT (epoch FROM tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time)/3600 as task_duration,
    consultants_select.consultant_cost_per_hour * (EXTRACT (epoch FROM tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time))/3600 as consultant_cost,
    clients_select.client_amount_per_hour * (EXTRACT (epoch FROM tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time))/3600 as client_amount,
    task_related_costs_per_hour * (EXTRACT (epoch FROM tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time))/3600 as task_cost_related
FROM consultants
INNER JOIN tasks ON consultants.id = tasks.consultant_id
INNER JOIN clients ON tasks.client_id = clients.id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        consultants.id as consultant_id,
      salaries.payment / (extract(epoch from sum(tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time)) / 3600) as consultant_cost_per_hour
    FROM consultants 
      INNER JOIN tasks ON consultants.id = tasks.consultant_id
      INNER JOIN salaries ON consultants.id = salaries.consultant_id
    GROUP BY consultants.id, to_char(salaries.payment_date, 'yyyy-mm'), salaries.payment
    ORDER BY consultant_id) AS consultants_select ON consultants.id = consultants_select.consultant_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
    clients.id as client_id,
    amount_client_month.amount_client / worked_client_month.worked_hours as client_amount_per_hour
    FROM 
        (SELECT
                    clients.id as client_id,
                    to_char(purchases.date, 'yyyy-mm') as client_year_month,
                    SUM(products.price) as amount_client
            FROM clients
                INNER JOIN purchases ON purchases.client_id = clients.id
                INNER JOIN products ON purchases.product_id = products.id
            GROUP BY clients.id, to_char(purchases.date, 'yyyy-mm')
            ORDER BY clients.id) AS amount_client_month
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT
            clients.id as client_id,
            to_char(tasks.init_time::date, 'yyyy-mm') as month,
            SUM(extract(epoch from (tasks.finish_time - tasks.init_time))) / 3600 as worked_hours
        FROM tasks
          INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id = tasks.client_id
        GROUP BY clients.id, to_char(tasks.init_time::date, 'yyyy-mm')) as worked_client_month
    ON amount_client_month.client_id = worked_client_month.client_id
    INNER JOIN clients ON worked_client_month.client_id = clients.id) AS clients_select ON clients.id = clients_select.client_id
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        tasks.id as task_id,
        SUM(costs.amount) as task_related_costs_per_hour
    FROM costs
    INNER JOIN task_costs ON costs.id = task_costs.cost_id
    INNER JOIN tasks ON task_costs.task_id = tasks.id
    GROUP BY tasks.id) AS tasks_select ON tasks.id = tasks_select.task_id;
```

Inside views I have the folder `reports\consultants_clients_tasks`

```
<h1>Report: ConsultantsClientsTasks</h1>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>consultant_name</th>
      <th>client_name</th>
      <th>task_name</th>
      <th>task_date</th>
      <th>task_duration</th>
      <th>consultant_cost</th>
      <th>client_amount</th>
      <th>task_cost_related</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @consultants_clients_tasks.each do |co| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= co.consultant_name %></td>
        <td><%= co.client_name %></td>
        <td><%= co.task_name %></td>
        <td><%= co.task_date %></td>
        <td><%= co.task_duration %></td>
        <td><%= co.consultant_cost %></td>
        <td><%= co.client_amount %></td>
        <td><%= co.task_cost_related %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Inside controllers I have a folder call `reports` with the file `consultants_clients_tasks_controller.rb`

```
class Reports::ConsultantsClientsTasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @consultants_clients_tasks = ConsultantsClientsTask.all
  end
end
```

Inside models I have the folder `reports` with the file `consultants_clients_task.rb`

```
module ReadOnlyModel
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class Reports::ConsultantsClientsTask < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "consultants_clients_tasks"
  end
end
```

and in the routes files I added

```
namespace :reports do
  get 'consultants_clients_tasks/index'
end
```

The first time I load into the page all works fine, the problem is when I refresh the page I get this errors

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is obvious as you are using a ***wrong class name***. You need to change

```
@consultants_clients_tasks = ConsultantsClientsTask.all
```

to

```
@consultants_clients_tasks = Reports::ConsultantsClientsTask.all
```